# evaluating gives identity on sets from the basic model

Tags: set-theory, filters, forcing

I have a very basic question about forcing and generic set:
why for $a\in M$ from the ground model do we have $$\dot{a}[G]=a$$ ?
Where it is used in this equality here that $a\in M$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposedly you're talking about $\check a$, the canonical name for $a\in M$.

In this case, the answer is by a simple $\in$-induction: Suppose that $a\in M$, and for all $b\in a$, $\check b[G]=b$. Since $\check a=\{(1_\Bbb P,\check b)\mid b\in a\}$ and $1_\Bbb P\in G$, we get that $\check a[G]=\{\check b[G]\mid b\in a\}$, but as we already assumed $\check b[G]=b$, so $\check a[G]=\{b\mid b\in a\}=a$.

Comment: I understand your induction argument but I do not know where exactly have you used $a\in M$ ?

Comment: Well, you want $\check a$ to be defined.

Comment: $\check{a}$ is always defined or not ?

Comment: It's only relevant for the elements of $M$. You don't care about *all* possible names, you care about those names of elements in $M$. And if $a\in M$, then $\check a\in M$. If $a\notin M$, then $\check a\notin M$.